# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I cannot figure out why I keep getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null
getFSREPlist
(anonymous function)

The error is referencing this line of code (21):

```
document.getElementById(elementidupdate).options.length=0;
```

What is weird is that it was working prior to this new google map api I just put on. Also, it is pulling the country code "1" and putting it in the drop down, but not the province code "19".

Here is the on page script:

```
getFSREPlist('1', 'fsrep-search-province', 'CountryID', '19');getFSREPlist('19', 'fsrep-search-city', 'ProvinceID', '3');           request.send(null);
```

Here is the full file:

```
   function sack(file) {
    this.xmlhttp = null;
    this.resetData = function () {
        this.method = "POST";
        this.queryStringSeparator = "?";
        this.argumentSeparator = "&";
        this.URLString = "";
        this.encodeURIString = true;
        this.execute = false;
        this.element = null;
        this.elementObj = null;
        this.requestFile = file;
        this.vars = new Object();
        this.responseStatus = new Array(2);
    };
    this.resetFunctions = function () {
        this.onLoading = function () {};
        this.onLoaded = function () {};
        this.onInteractive = function () {};
        this.onCompletion = function () {};
        this.onError = function () {};
        this.onFail = function () {};
    };
    this.reset = function () {
        this.resetFunctions();
        this.resetData();
    };
    this.createAJAX = function () {
        try {
            this.xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e1) {
            try {
                this.xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e2) {
                this.xmlhttp = null;
            }
        }
        if (!this.xmlhttp) {
            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
                this.xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                this.failed = true;
            }
        }
    };
    this.setVar = function (name, value) {
        this.vars[name] = Array(value, false);
    };
    this.encVar = function (name, value, returnvars) {
        if (true == returnvars) {
            return Array(encodeURIComponent(name), encodeURIComponent(value));
        } else {
            this.vars[encodeURIComponent(name)] = Array(encodeURIComponent(value), true);
        }
    }
    this.processURLString = function (string, encode) {
        encoded = encodeURIComponent(this.argumentSeparator);
        regexp = new RegExp(this.argumentSeparator + "|" + encoded);
        varArray = string.split(regexp);
        for (i = 0; i < varArray.length; i++) {
            urlVars = varArray[i].split("=");
            if (true == encode) {
                this.encVar(urlVars[0], urlVars[1]);
            } else {
                this.setVar(urlVars[0], urlVars[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    this.createURLString = function (urlstring) {
        if (this.encodeURIString && this.URLString.length) {
            this.processURLString(this.URLString, true);
        }
        if (urlstring) {
            if (this.URLString.length) {
                this.URLString += this.argumentSeparator + urlstring;
            } else {
                this.URLString = urlstring;
            }
        }
        this.setVar("rndval", new Date().getTime());
        urlstringtemp = new Array();
        for (key in this.vars) {
            if (false == this.vars[key][1] && true == this.encodeURIString) {
                encoded = this.encVar(key, this.vars[key][0], true);
                delete this.vars[key];
                this.vars[encoded[0]] = Array(encoded[1], true);
                key = encoded[0];
            }
            urlstringtemp[urlstringtemp.length] = key + "=" + this.vars[key][0];
        }
        if (urlstring) {
            this.URLString += this.argumentSeparator + urlstringtemp.join(this.argumentSeparator);
        } else {
            this.URLString += urlstringtemp.join(this.argumentSeparator);
        }
    }
    this.runResponse = function () {
        eval(this.response);
    }
    this.runAJAX = function (urlstring) {
        if (this.failed) {
            this.onFail();
        } else {
            this.createURLString(urlstring);
            if (this.element) {
                this.elementObj = document.getElementById(this.element);
            }
            if (this.xmlhttp) {
                var self = this;
                if (this.method == "GET") {
                    totalurlstring = this.requestFile + this.queryStringSeparator + this.URLString;
                    this.xmlhttp.open(this.method, totalurlstring, true);
                } else {
                    this.xmlhttp.open(this.method, this.requestFile, true);
                    try {
                        this.xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    } catch (e) {}
                }
                this.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    switch (self.xmlhttp.readyState) {
                        case 1:
                            self.onLoading();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            self.onLoaded();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            self.onInteractive();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            self.response = self.xmlhttp.responseText;
                            self.responseXML = self.xmlhttp.responseXML;
                            self.responseStatus[0] = self.xmlhttp.status;
                            self.responseStatus[1] = self.xmlhttp.statusText;
                            if (self.execute) {
                                self.runResponse();
                            }
                            if (self.elementObj) {
                                elemNodeName = self.elementObj.nodeName;
                                elemNodeName.toLowerCase();
                                if (elemNodeName == "input" || elemNodeName == "select" || elemNodeName == "option" || elemNodeName == "textarea") {
                                    self.elementObj.value = self.response;
                                } else {
                                    self.elementObj.innerHTML = self.response;
                                }
                            }
                            if (self.responseStatus[0] == "200") {
                                self.onCompletion();
                            } else {
                                self.onError();
                            }
                            self.URLString = "";
                            break;
                    }
                };
                this.xmlhttp.send(this.URLString);
            }
        }
    };
    this.reset();
    this.createAJAX();
}
var ajax = new Array();

function getFSREPlist(sel, elementidupdate, fsrepvariable, currentvalue) {
    if (sel == '[object]' || sel == '[object HTMLSelectElement]') {
        var FSREPID = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    } else {
        var FSREPID = sel;
    }
    document.getElementById(elementidupdate).options.length = 0;
    var index = ajax.length;
    ajax[index] = new sack();
    ajax[index].requestFile = 'http://www.cabcot.com/wp-content/plugins/firestorm-real-estate-plugin/search.php?' + fsrepvariable + '=' + FSREPID + '&cvalue=' + currentvalue;
    ajax[index].onCompletion = function () {
        ElementUpdate(index, elementidupdate)
    };
    ajax[index].runAJAX();
}

function ElementUpdate(index, elementidupdate) {
    var obj = document.getElementById(elementidupdate);
    eval(ajax[index].response);
}
```

Comment: Do format your code make it readable.

Comment: `document.getElementById(elementidupdate)` is null. Have you defined an element with value `elementidupdate` variable

Comment: @Satpal - I am confused about this script. I can't figure out why it is null for one of the variables (provinces) but country works just fine. I don't know why my brain isn't working today. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Satpal It should be coming from here I think:  echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('Select a State/Province','');\n";
 foreach ($FSREPProvinces as $FSREPProvinces) {
  echo "obj.options[obj.options.length] = new Option('".$FSREPProvinces->province_name."','".$FSREPProvinces->province_id."');\n";
  if ($FSREPProvinces->province_id == $_GET['cvalue']) {
   echo "obj.options[$count].selected = true;";
  }
  $count++;
 }

Comment: @Satpal I am still not figuring it out. God, I know it has to be so easy. What am I missing?

Comment: See generated HTML of element, that will help you. I am not good with PHP.

Comment: @Satpal - It is producing the following element: getFSREPlist('1', 'fsrep-search-province', 'CountryID', '19');getFSREPlist('19', 'fsrep-search-city', 'ProvinceID', '');   request.send(null);

Comment: @Satpal - Here is the URL: http://www.cabcot.com/. If you type in the search a Country it will drop down the province. The problem is after clicking search it will loses the province, but keeps the Country information.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `getFSREPlist` when DOM is loaded. I ran

```
document.getElementById('fsrep-search-province').options.length=0
```

from `chrome´s console`. while page was still loading and caused that same error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JFi2.png

Comment: I think you are right. I tried the following, but I must be coding it wrong: $(function ElementUpdate(index, elementidupdate))
{
 var obj = document.getElementById(elementidupdate);
 eval(ajax[index].response); 
});

Comment: Well, I think it would be easier:

roll back all those changes you applied and edit just this block of code (currently at line 86 on index):

    getFSREPlist('2', 'fsrep-search-province', 'CountryID','3');
    getFSREPlist('3', 'fsrep-search-city', 'ProvinceID', '31');       request.send(null);

to:

    $(function(){
        getFSREPlist('2', 'fsrep-search-province', 'CountryID', '3');
        getFSREPlist('3', 'fsrep-    search-city', 'ProvinceID', '31');
        request.send(null);
    });

Comment: I tried the code above, but it doesn't work with wordpress, so I went with another method: jQuery(document).ready(function ($){getFSREPlist('1', 'fsrep-search-province', 'CountryID', '19'); getFSREPlist('19', 'fsrep-search-city', 'ProvinceID', '34'); request.send(null); }); ----------Now it is throwing a different code and is working. Here is the new error code:  Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined (index):86
(anonymous function) (index):86
(anonymous function) jquery.js?ver=1.3.2:1
o.extend.each jquery.js?ver=1.3.2:1
o.extend.ready jquery.js?ver=1.3.2:1

Comment: what is supposed to do with that request and where is set?
also, you have another error at line 44

http://www.cabcot.com/wp-content/plugins/firestorm-real-estate-plugin/xml/marker_listings.php?search= empty param result in 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getElementsByTagName' of null